How to subdivide the bibliography, with each subdivision having a different order, while sharing the same bibliography 'chapter'?
I am compiling the bibliography for my work, a Book, which is subdivided into Main and References. The ones in Main are not cited, while those in References are, as they are articles.
The closest I came to my search was to include the following in the preamble:
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=bibtex,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
\nocite{Book5 Author}
\nocite{Book3 AuthorC}
\nocite{Book1 AuthorA}
\nocite{Book4 AuthorD}
\nocite{Book2 AuthorB}

and then at the end of the document:
\printbibliography[title={Further Reading},notcategory=cited]
\printbibliography[category=cited]

With this, both lists appeared, but the problem is that both bibliographies are separated by a page, and the order in Main is alphabetical. I tried to fix it by adding sorting=none to \usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=bibtex,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}, but this change also applied to the References, and I want them to remain in the alphabetical order.
I tried creating another .bib file for Main, but the problem persists.
This is my target

Code:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=bibtex,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}


\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mainandreferences.bib}
@article{Article1,
    author = {John Doe and Jane Smith},
    title = {Quantum Computing},
    year = {2023}
}

@article{Article2,
    author = {Alice Johnson and Robert White},
    title = {AI in Healthcare},
    year = {2022}
}

@article{Article3,
    author = {Michael Brown and Sarah Lee},
    title = {Renewable Energy in Cities},
    year = {2021}
}

@article{Article4,
    author = {Emily Davis and Chris Wilson},
    title = {Social Media Trends},
    year = {2020}
}

@article{Article5,
    author = {James Taylor and Linda Martinez},
    title = {Blockchain in Finance},
    year = {2024}
}
@book{Book5,
    author = {Author E},
    title = {Book Title 5},
    year = {2020},
    publisher = {Publisher 5}
}

@book{Book3,
    author = {Author C},
    title = {Book Title 3},
    year = {2019},
    publisher = {Publisher 3}
}

@book{Book1,
    author = {Author A},
    title = {Book Title 1},
    year = {2021},
    publisher = {Publisher 1}
}

@book{Book4,
    author = {Author D},
    title = {Book Title 4},
    year = {2018},
    publisher = {Publisher 4}
}

@book{Book2,
    author = {Author B},
    title = {Book Title 2},
    year = {2017},
    publisher = {Publisher 2}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{mainandreferences.bib}

%MY ORDER
\nocite{Book5}
\nocite{Book3}
\nocite{Book1}
\nocite{Book4}
\nocite{Book2}


\begin{document}
    
\cite{Article1} \cite{Article5} \cite{Article3} \cite{Article2} \cite{Article4} 
    
\printbibliography[title={Main},notcategory=cited]
\printbibliography[title={References}category=cited]

    
\end{document}


Different sorting templates are only supported with Biber and not with the legacy BibTeX backend. So you need to switch to backend=biber, and need to tell your editor to run Biber for you: Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations.
As far as I understand the two lists are kept separate, so you can use refsections. (refsections are completely independent bibliography lists.) For your "main", you create a new refsection with local refcontext, whose sorting is none. Then within that refsection you \nocite the relevant work in the expected order.
For the normal "references", you just cite outside this special refsection as usual.
For the headings, use \printbibheading for the overall heading and heading=subbibliography, for the \printbibliographys.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=verbose-ibid,
]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{mainandreferences.bib}
@article{Article1,
    author = {John Doe and Jane Smith},
    title = {Quantum Computing},
    year = {2023}
}
@article{Article2,
    author = {Alice Johnson and Robert White},
    title = {AI in Healthcare},
    year = {2022}
}
@article{Article3,
    author = {Michael Brown and Sarah Lee},
    title = {Renewable Energy in Cities},
    year = {2021}
}
@article{Article4,
    author = {Emily Davis and Chris Wilson},
    title = {Social Media Trends},
    year = {2020}
}
@article{Article5,
    author = {James Taylor and Linda Martinez},
    title = {Blockchain in Finance},
    year = {2024}
}
@book{Book5,
    author = {Author E},
    title = {Book Title 5},
    year = {2020},
    publisher = {Publisher 5}
}
@book{Book3,
    author = {Author C},
    title = {Book Title 3},
    year = {2019},
    publisher = {Publisher 3}
}
@book{Book1,
    author = {Author A},
    title = {Book Title 1},
    year = {2021},
    publisher = {Publisher 1}
}
@book{Book4,
    author = {Author D},
    title = {Book Title 4},
    year = {2018},
    publisher = {Publisher 4}
}
@book{Book2,
    author = {Author B},
    title = {Book Title 2},
    year = {2017},
    publisher = {Publisher 2}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{mainandreferences.bib}

\begin{document}
Normal \autocite{Article1}
citations \autocite{Article5}
in \autocite{Article3}
the \autocite{Article2}
text \autocite{Article4} 

\printbibheading
\begin{refsection}
\newrefcontext[sorting=none]
\nocite{Book5}
\nocite{Book3}
\nocite{Book1}
\nocite{Book4}
\nocite{Book2}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Main}]
\end{refsection}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={References}]    
\end{document}



Perfect! Thank you very much, I hope you had a Merry Christmas and I wish you a Happy New Year.
